# How can I get the full size of a Tree View in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I don't have the "AutoSize" option in TreeView, but I need to know what's the full height and the full width that the object is taking. I can only define the size of the TreeView panel, which shows scrollbar when the content overlaps the referred size.

Is there a way to know how big really is the content displayed?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the absolute bottom of the content area (only what's expanded), then you can use the Nodes property with the Bounds property to get the visible height.

```
TreeNode tn = tv.Nodes[tv.Nodes.Count - 1];
while(tn.IsExpanded)
    tn = tn.Nodes[tn.Nodes.Count - 1];
return tn.Bounds.Bottom;
```

Just be sure to have proper error checking (TreeView actually HAS nodes, etc). As for the width, can't remember exactly how I did it. However, you might be able to use the TreeView's Bounds property itself (might require some testing). I had a similar situation, where I didn't have an AutoSizing TreeView, but it was contained in a panel and fill docked, so I needed to handle the scrollbars myself by resizing the treeview on Expand/Collapse.

Comment: Actually, it is exactly my situation! I'll try this and come back with a feedback. Thanks for now!

Comment: I can't remember if you need to add each of the Bottom bounds or not, but at least this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Well, I didn`t used exactly your solution, but I won't put mine here because it was really specific for my case, but I used the "bounds" data to get all the height and width, looking for the Max value with nested LINQ. Thank you for clarifying this!